# click on a link in a table, then check in what row the link was

Tags: php, href, html-table

What I want to make is this:

I am making a blog. Now I want a query in my mysql-database that finds all the information that is in there. After that it should echo the title's of the blog's on my site in a table.

Then I would like to give people a choice which blog they would like to see. So when they click on the first title they will see the content of that blog.

So now the problem is that I don't know how I can make href's on every title that all go to another php file. In that file it should know which row/title is clicked and then it should make another query in the database that will find the content of that title. Then it should echo it on the site.

**I got the table finished. I also know how to make the href's to the other page. the only thing I need to know is which title/href is clicked.**

Is it possible to make this with php only? if yes, please explain me how.

I hope I am clear in what i would like to make.

EDIT: this is my code so far:

```
 <?php
session_start();
    $connectie = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'usbw');
    if ($connectie == false){
        echo 'Er is iets fout gegaan met de connectie van de database';
    }

    if (mysql_select_db('dldatabase', $connectie) == false) {
    echo 'Er kon geen verbinding met de database gemaakt worden';
    }

    $query = "Select *
        from forum";
    $resultaat = mysql_query($query, $connectie);
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Tijd</th>
    <th>Gebruikersnaam</th>

    <th>Titel</th>
    </tr>";


`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat))
  {
  $_SESSION['row'] = $row;
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Tijd'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Gebruikersnaam'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . '<a class="formtitellink" href="forumdocument.php">' . $row['Titel'] . '</a>' . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";`
```

this is the blog page

and this is where the content of the blog should be±

```
session_start();
$row = $_SESSION['row'];
$row = $row + 1;
$query = "Select titel, inhoud
        from forum
        where `ID` = '$row'";
$resultaat = mysql_query($query, $connectie);
echo "$resultaat";
```

Comment: Could you show us the code? What have you done so far?

Comment: Have a think about how GET parameters on a URL work and how you might use them in a PHP script.  Once you've got to the point where you can post some code that shows that basic understanding, you might get some people following up with some help.

Comment: Please clarify if what you want is the code for the whole blog or just the logic behind clicking on a td with a link which calls another script that shows the content. Everything you want seems possible with php but for help I require more specificity in the question

Comment: I posted my code in the question :).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a framework like Wordpress, but if you want this kind of structure from scratch then you should read more about URL manipulation and use of GET parameters.

Simplest solution will be:

1. Create a page say post.php
2. Now every time you want a post to be displayed, send it with get
   parameter. For eg: "page.php?id=hello-world"
3. On post.php, you can read this "id" parameter and then fire a
   query accordingly.
4. Then print the resultant data on page.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to pages like first page and the second page to open as hyper link.
Here is the sample code:

```
<?php

                echo '<table width="650"><p><tr><th style="margin-left: 10px; padding-right: 70px;"></th> 
                                                        <th style="width: 350px; ">Item for sale</th> <th>Location</th> <th>Posted</th></tr></table>';


                        $query1 = "select id from tblads order by priority desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1";
                        $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
                        $i1 = 0;


                        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_row($result1)) 
                        {   

                            $count1 = count($row1);
                            $y1 = 0;

                            while ($y1<$count1)
                            {
                            $c_row1 = current($row1);

                            $id = $c_row1;


                            next($row1);
                            $y1 = $y1 + 1;



                                                //////TABLE     
                                            echo'<style> th{padding:0;}</style> ';


                                            echo '<table style="  table-layout:fixed; order-collapse: collapse; " width="650">';
                                echo '<tr> <th> </th> <th style="width:350px;"> </th> <th style=""></th> <th style="width:100px;"></th></tr>';

                                            $query = "select image,details, location, date from tblads where id=$id";
                                            $result = mysql_query($query);                                                                                  
                                            if (!$result) {$message = 'ERROR:' . mysql_error();return $message;}
                                            else
                                            {   $i = $i1;


                                            $i = 0;
                                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
                                            {                                                                                                                                               
                                            echo '<tr>  ';
                                            $count = count($row);
                                            $y = 0;
                                            while ($y < $count)
                                            {
                                                $c_row = current($row);                                                                 
                                                echo '<td style=""><a href="view.php?id='.$id.'">' . $c_row . '</a></td>';
                                                next($row);
                                                    $y = $y + 1;
                                            }
                                            echo ' </tr>';
                                            $i = $i + 1;                        
                                            }

                                            }                                                       
                                }

                            echo'</table>';     //Content TABLE CLOSE


                        }   

                mysql_free_result($result); mysql_close($con);                                              
            ?>
```

Then the second page view.php to be opened by the hyperlink:

```
<?php
                $id=$_GET['id'];




            $query = "select image, details, location, price, date, id from tblads where id=$id";
                        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) 
            {
                $message = 'ERROR:' . mysql_error();
                return $message;
            }
            else
            {   $i = 0;
                echo '<table><p><tr>';
                    while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result))
                    {
                        $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
                        echo '<th>' . $meta->name . '</th>';

                        $i = $i + 1;

                    }
                    echo '<th>View</th></tr>';

                    $i = 0;
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
                    {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        $count = count($row);
                        $y = 0;
                        while ($y < $count)
                    {
                        $c_row = current($row);
                        echo '<td>' . $c_row . '</td>';
                        next($row);
                        $y = $y + 1;
                    }
                        echo '<td></td> </tr>';
                        $i = $i + 1;

                    }
                        echo' </p></table>';
                        mysql_free_result($result);


                    mysql_close($con); 

                    }


            ?>
```